# Why do interpretivist ignore basic statistical assumptions when supporting their theories by empirical evidence?

Tags: epistemology, marx, interpretation

Interpretivism is the stance that the social realm cannot be studied with the same methods as the natural realm.

Although I personally don't belief this assumption is true I can understand some approaches followed by interpretivist. For example building from axioms such as Marx did and ponder what the consequences are in the future.

However many interpretivists such as Frankfurt school and also Marx used a method which is best characterized by a mixture of positivst and interpretivist methodology. To be more clear, there is always some data gathering, although highly selective, basically cherry-picking as such that it supports their theories.

While I can see how someone believes that natural and social realm are fundamentally different, how do interpretivist justify ignoring basic results from formal sciences such as statistics, i.e. sampling as such as to reduce sampling bias. Formal sciences are closer to interpretivist social science than to natural sciences and are thought to be universal.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek-comment: Consider how many people doing quantitative social sciences are actually bad at applying basic statistical assumptions in their methods and interpretation 

Comment: You are talking about one guy who wrote long before economics even became a quantitative science and a philosopher here. My comment refers to guys who are trained and working in modern day quantitative sciences. And even they are more often than not bad at working statistical analysis properly.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I misunderstood your comment

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yes but interpretivist approaches are more common than ever before in the social sciences especially in sociology and its derivatives...Frankfurt school popularized it..

Comment: The problem is that Wikipedia, from which the ["definition"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipositivism) of interpretivism is taken, is not big on precision or nuance. Their position is not that humanities "cannot be studied" by methods of natural science, but rather that those methods are grossly insufficient because they abstract from individuality and subjective experiences. Hence, they must be complemented by hermeneutics, etc. That is how the father of interpretivism, Dilthey, argued it, for example, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dilthey/#N188BroaCritFram).

Comment: @Conifold How does that influence why sampling theorem by statistician can be ignored while gathering empirical evidence?

Comment: @Rubus Because the main argument in favour of interpretivism is exactly that social sciences need to overemphasise the existence of the problems of minorities and fringe cases as it is the edges where problems come to light best? It is yet another instance of the old "social sciences should only describe what is" vs. "social sciences should include value judgements as society is all about values".

Comment: So then social science becomes the narrative that best suits the political agenda of minorities / fringe ideas opposed to an objective description. Values are ultimately arbitrary...

Comment: To make this comment thread on-topic again: Your question seems to be based on the assumption that only (statistically) unbiased description can fit the bill of social *sciences*. At the same time, you are descrediting the exposition of fringe ideas or consequences for minorities as "political agenda" and "arbitrary". Isn't that biased as well? And do you realise that *any* assertion based on data is ultimately an *interpretation*? Are we forbidden to point out inequalities and possible trends as *problematic* in social sciences now?

Comment: While there are axiomatic methods in the social science, I think social science is best conducted gathering empirical evidence. Empirical evidence needs statistics to gather unbiased evidence. This can only be accomplished by adhering to statistical assumptions. When you say overemphasize I read it as such that you gather more evidence regarding minorities / fringe cases which would give a biased sample thus disregarding statistics...

Comment: When you arbitrarily inflate a problem I would consider it part of a political agenda, since if interested in truth you wouldn't consider that. This is why the quesion asks about the rationale why interpretivists do this? Is there some epistemiological benefit in disregarding basic statistics or is it to foster political agenda?

Comment: Yes any assertion is an interpretion. However objectivity exists, it is accomplished by using statistical methods to gather empirical evidence, or even better finding analytical solutions which so far seems not possible in the social science. (although economics tries that)..Data gathering is obviously needed in the social science, but should adhere to statistical assumptions and not where the prevailing ideology dictates it...

Comment: To be more clear consider Frankfurt school. Apart from some observations regarding Soviet Union they never criticize any alternative to capitalism. They only base their observations on capitalism. Thus their evidence is highly biased. (sampling bias is very high to max). Sociologists point out that capitalism is the prevailing system. However this does not allow them to only base their evidence on capitalist systems, at least not according to sampling theorem. So then the question remains, why It is done in this manner apart from political agenda / ideology?

Comment: If one is interested in subjective experiences and perspectives statistics and objectivity are of limited value to them. Truth extends beyond objective descriptions, and something else has to cover that ground. But I am not sure why you take the platitude that statistics, or any other method, is not useful for everything to mean that it would be rejected where it is of use, such as empirical studies. Statisticians do what they do, and interpretivists do what statisticians are incapable of doing, and vice versa. Whether their motives are political, ethical, aesthetic, psychological or whatever.

Comment: @Conifold "Truth extends beyond objective descriptions." How can that be? How can you determine what is true and what is only an illusion? I'm not arguing for interpretivism, but against it. I think allowing interpretivst research to equate to empirical research will ultimately degrade into using "science" to foster a political agenda. Something which is much harder using emprism....

Comment: What does "equate" even mean? We have art beside science, don't we? Are they "equated"? We also have religions, ideologies, morality, games. Objective truth is one value, it is not the only one, and people will pursue all of them one way or another. Even illusions and delusions have subjective truth to them, that is why we value fiction, and there is plenty of room between science and fiction as well. Human mind has diverse interests, instead of arguing for one pursuit against another we can benefit from both in their own element, live and let live.

Comment: equate = regard as equal. I rather have social science based on rigorous empiricism rather than interpretivism since the potential for misuse is just too high, plus I doubt interpretivism being able to answer question of high importance such as empiricsm can. Yes religions, ideologies, morality, games, etc etc exist. Do they help in establishing truth? I think it's rather the opposite. We need important questions answered, something only rigorous empiricism can. The alternative is that everybody just opinionated their favorite biasis and we never progress. The progress in the sciences is due

Comment: to empiricism and not some vague ill-defined subjective interpretation or meta-phyiscal speculation. These have never served anybody besides people engaging in such activities or as justification for political gains...

Comment: One might distinguish interpretivists who think it is *in principle* impossible to study the social realm with positivist methods, vs. those who just think it's necessary in practice to use less "scientific" methods because the relevant scientific experiments are too difficult to perform for the forseeable future (for example, the ideal positivist style test of Marx's historical materialism would be to have multiple independent historical "experiments" where humans start from hunter-gatherer conditions and develop more advanced technologies over time)

Comment: (cont.) This issue applies to other big theories of long-term historical change, see for example Jared Diamond's comments about the impossibility of repeated historical experiments in [this section of the epilogue to *Guns, Germs and Steel*](https://www.d.umn.edu/~tbacig/cst1010/chs/diamond.html).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Obviously social science has its limitations as you correctly pointed out. However looking at fundamental statistical theory which is ignored by interpretatists the problem is not that they aspire to reach the same methodological rigour as natural scientists do and fail due to inherent limitations imposed by the social realm, instead they deliberately disregard even the most basic statistical approaches...

Comment: @Hypnosifl The article you linked is basically my position. There are several limitations. However compared to what interpretivists do, there is huge potential for improvement. This paragraph makes it very clear "While neither astronomers studying galaxy formation nor human historians can manipulate their systems in controlled laboratory experiments, they both can take advantage of natural experiments, by comparing systems differing in the presence or absence (or in the strong or weak effect) of some putative causative factor. " Compare that to what Frankfurt school does...

Comment: I have to assume you do not really have a question here but just an opinion in disguise which you will discuss and defend as you have made up your mind already. That is not what StackExchange works like. And bashing "Frankfurt School" will get you nowhere. There are four generations of philosophers and a huge amount of psychology, economics, and also statistically sound quantitative analysis that is affiliated to that term. Either you edit the question to include particular instances or I'll have to close as opinionated.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Can you reference the statistically sound quantitative analysis regarding economics authored by Frankfurt school philosophers? Or should I post it as a separate question? It's pretty difficult to change one's mind when there are zero references given. Also the initial question still stands, why interpretivists disregard basic statics when amending their theories by empirical evidence.. So far no explanation has been given, other than that there are other truths than empirical ones, which was not the question.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking *And bashing "Frankfurt School" will get you nowhere. There are four generations of philosophers and a huge amount of psychology, economics, and also statistically sound quantitative analysis that is affiliated to that term.* Such as? I'm not aware of any such "statistically sound quantitative analysis" affiliated with the Frankfurt School, which is a school of continental philosophy.

Comment: @user76284 The Frankfurt School is the *Institut für Sozialforschung*, which is the school/institute that is the namesake. This institute does and always did, among other things, empirical sociology. The idea behind the founding was exactly to have a multidisciplinary institute. The continental philosophy by Adorno and Horkheimer most people link to that term is but a tiny fraction of the work done in that institute which continues to exist to this day.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Again, can you cite any examples?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking And "the Frankfurt School" does not mean "anything done at the University of Frankfurt Institute for Social Research", just like "the Chicago School" [of economics] does not mean "anything done at the University of Chicago". It refers to something more specific: a particular school of philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin by saying that 'interpretivism' — not a term I've used before, but will here for the sake of the discussion —  does not reject applications of the natural sciences in the absolute sense implied here. It is quite willing to use procedures such as statistical analysis when and where they are helpful. The problem is that the methods of the natural sciences aren't always that helpful; they are not sophisticated enough to address the kinds of problems that a society provides.

The natural sciences are powerful because they are able make a number of useful assumptions:

- **Non-identity**: different items of a given 'type' can be swapped indifferently, because they share precisely the same properties

  - two object of the same mass will fall the same way in a vacuum; two samples of a given compound will react chemically in the same way; etc.
- **Continuity**: every object of a given category will retain the same properties and tendencies across different times and places

  - a drop of water will behave exactly the same in any place and any time, so long as the conditions for maintaining a drop of water exist.
- **Conservation**: a system remains in energy balance unless disturbed by an outside force

  - principles of inertia, thermodynamic equilibrium, etc.

These assumptions allow natural scientists to reduce dimensions of analysis and simplify equations until the equations are actually solvable. For instance, if we want to know how a thrown object behaves, we don't have to think about whether it's a baseball, bowling ball, or bag of duck feathers. We don't have to worry about whether we're in Africa, Asia, or Europe; we don't need to remember whether it's Thursday (in case things work differently on Thursdays). We never have a problem with objects suddenly changing course of their own volition. All we need to know is mass, initial force, and angle of trajectory, and we're good to go. And no, obviously it's never perfect, but any inconsistency can be attributed to measurement errors (which we can improve on) or unanticipated forces (which we can anticipate and account for).

Natural science *works* because it can make simplifications and approximations that work very well for most purposes. They excel where they can take a hard problem and make it (comparatively) easy.

These assumptions don't really apply to the social world. They don't even apply to all of the natural world, to be frank — think turbulence, non-linear dynamics, quantum entanglement — but in the social world it's often a blatant error to make them. I mean, could you and I switch places without any impact on the social world around us? Do we behave exactly the same now as we did when we were six, or as our stone-age ancestors did? Do we simply bounce around like molecules in a solution, neither adding to nor detracting from the world around us? Maybe... But those are really challenging assumptions to make about the social, human world.

And note, this hasn't even gotten to the question of ***value*** which has no easy correlate in the natural sciences. I mean, the natural sciences can manipulate the physical properties of certain materials to produce nuclear fission, but there is no natural sciences distinction between the fission that occurs in a power plant and the fission that occurs in a bomb. There's a *human* distinction between the two — one heats and lights my house and the other reduces my house to radioactive rubble — but there's no 'scientific' reason to build or not to build the bomb. How would we begin to analyze nuclear proliferation politics using the methods of the natural sciences? What statistical analysis tells us how many and who should be incinerated?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134365/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-why-do-interpretivist-ignore-basic-statistic).